# R - "what is a function within a function"

Tags: r, function

Context is that I am still learning R as a beginner. Can I explain the concept of "a function within a function" as below?

> It works like "in" and "out"- you give a
>   function in, another function comes out.

For example:

`addsth<-function(xx){function(yy){xx+yy}}`

- function of xx goes in, function of yy comes out (inside of function of yy, yy goes in, xx+yy comes out)

`addsth(7)`

- means it is a function of 7, 7 goes in, function(yy){xx+yy} needs to come out. 
  Now 7 "flow into" the body of what needs to come out the body says yy goes it take a value of 7, xx+yy comes out when all is ready to invoke, which also means I have to define xx for it to operate.

That definition cannot be assigned as a value, like xx=9, but it needs to be assigned within a function to satisfy the requirement to invoke. 
Therefore: now since addsth(7) only defines a function, it needs to be given a value of xx

```
afteradd<-addsth(7) 
afteradd(1000) 
returns 1007
```

many thanks!

Comment: look into switch statement, with each statement has another function into it

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what your question is. `addsth()` - to be exact - is a "closure". The function it self doesn't change, but "*The parent environment of a closure is the execution environment of the function that created it*" (Wickham)
The book 'Advanced R' by Hadley Wickham explains this pretty well, and is actually available online: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html

Hope this helps a little.